# Reload the panel in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Please have a look at my [Autodesk Viewer](https://github.com/eugsterli/OpenhabIOTForge/blob/master/forgeViewerTest/Scripts/SmokeDetectorsExtension.js) extension

I am try to reload the `Extension/Panel`

My extension SmokeDetectorsExtension will load once when the viewer was loading the file. In my docking panel called SimplePanel I want to show some IOT sensors data. and this needs to be refreshed.

So is there a possiblity to unload and reload the whole extention?

can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the name of the function you're calling, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a bit more details/context about the problem you are facing? The event ***Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT*** is only fired once when the model gets loaded, so if you try to reload the extension after that event has been fired it will not work ...

You could store the instanceTree so if you reload the extension it is directly available, just an example:

```
if (this.instanceTree) {

     //...

} else {

    viewer.addEventListener(
        Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, function () {

            this.instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree
            //... 
        } 
}
```

Comment: added some infos, can you show me some example code?